# Merging two partitions

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning

I wrongly made two partitions with Boot Camp in the following way:

[image]

I found many solutions around the web but I don't want to lose any data from my hard drive.

How can I merge the partitions via terminal or any program?

Comment: Is there any data on "Untitled"? If not, then you can use Disk Utility to delete it, then append the freed space to Macintosh HD.

Comment: Have you tried using Boot Camp to remove the partition yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the Disk Utility will not erase anything from Macintosh HD.

First, copy any file there can be on `Untitled` to `Macintosh HD` that you don't want to lose (if there's nothing on `Untitled`, proceed).

Open the Disk Utility (it's in /Applications/Utilities). In the left bar, select your hard drive. From there, click the "Partition" tab in the right pane.

[image: Select the drive]

You'll see the "physical" partitioning of your drive there.

[image]

Select your `Untitled` partition, and click the minus sign. The Disk Utility will ask you to confirm your choice, and will tell you that no other partition will be affected. Proceed.

[image]

(No more screenshots from here, because I didn't want to delete my Windows partition.) Once done, drag the bottom-right corner of your `Macintosh HD` drive to the bottom of the rectangle, and click "Apply". Disk Utility will possibly ask you to confirm again.

Job's done!

Comment: It's never too much to say this: always, **always** do a **backup** before messing up with partitions.